# System.EntryPointNotFoundException error when trying to run Bastion

Tags: 10.04, games

I have downloaded Bastion for Ubuntu and installed in the home folder normally.

When executing "Games > Bastion" nothing happens. Running Bastion directly from the installation folder results in the error below

```
Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: glProgramParameteri
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL/Core:ProgramParameteri (uint,OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.AssemblyProgramParameterArb,int)
  at OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.ProgramParameter (Int32 program, AssemblyProgramParameterArb pname, Int32 value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.EffectPass.ApplyPass () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Effect.DefineTechnique (System.String techniqueName, System.String passName, Int32 vertexIndex, Int32 fragmentIndex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteEffect..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GSGE.ExceptionGame.LoadContent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
<snip>
```

I have tried some solutions on the internet, like adding OpenTK.dll.config the line below:

```
<dllmap os="linux" dll="libXi" target="libXi.so.6"/>
```

This didn't help. Also tried running as sudo and that didn't help. Some posts said that this might be a problem with Ubuntu noveau drivers. But I'm using the NVIDIA proprietary drivers.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS"

OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 9400 GT/PCI/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 3.2.0 NVIDIA 195.36.24
direct rendering: Yes
```

Comment: `<dllmap os="linux" dll="libXi" target="libXi.so.6"/>` this is for mouse problems not for your problem!

Comment: I was desperate

Comment: I have the exact same problem in Fedora 16 and with intel gm965, so, its not the OS or a Nvidia specific problem.

Comment: That is a good information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was receiving the same error with the version Bastion-HIB-2012-05-29-1.sh released in the humble bundle, without delving deeper it seems to me that on some configurations the static links are incorrect.
There is a new build available, Bastion-HIB-2012-06-01-1.sh which resolved the problem for me.

My system is also Ubuntu 10.4 running the nVidia drivers

Comment: You are correct, this solved it. I played the game for quite a while, pretty good. (As a side note, after 3-4 hours playing my computer overheated and somehow is not working anymore I don't blame the game, the computer was quite bad even before this)

Comment: lucky you. I am still having the problem with the build from 2012-06-20

Answer (score 0):

`<dllmap os="linux" dll="libXi" target="libXi.so.6"/>`

That is for mouse problems not for your problem! - thanks a lot, that fixed my mouse problem in Bastion! Combined with`force_s3tc_enable=true`, `/usr/local/games/Bastion/Bastion.bin.x86_64` it is quite playable now (just need to take care of that rain further in the game).